# How Do I Convert Tensor using tf.keras.backend.eval?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a custom_accuracy function to include during `model.compile`, so I can monitor my custom metric in `EarlyStopping`, `ModelCheckpoint`, and `ReduceLROnPlateau`.

Then I found that Keras calls my custom_accuracy function with Tensors, not Numpy Arrays. I tried to convert them into Numpy using [`tf.keras.backend.eval`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/eval).

However, I get follow error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dense_3_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?] [[{{node dense_3_target}}]]
```

It seems eval accepts only one parameter x (Tensor to convert). How do I create placeholder and feed it? I'd appreciate any guidance!

Here's the testing code.

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
def custom_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_np = K.eval(y_true)
    y_pred_np = K.eval(y_pred)
```

Comment: Need to see more code to help you.There is a placeholder that must be fed with data. Add the code where you define `y_true` and `y_pred`

Comment: I just feed numpy array to model.fit, and I believe Keras itself calls custom_accuracy with those parameters. I think I would need to modify Keras itself to intervene a step before my function.

Comment: if `y_true` and `y_pred` are numpy arrays, why do you use `K.eval()` on numpy array?

Comment: I feed Keras Numpy arrays, and Keras does some calculation in Tensorflow, and it calls my function with Tensors.